# add record function in Kendo UI grid is called many times

Tags: javascript, ajax, kendo-grid

I am using this html code for Keno UI grid

```
function loadPhoneGrid(salesRepsId){
                        $("#phone-grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: "operations/get_phones_sales_reps.php?salesRepsId="+salesRepsId,
                                    type: "GET"
                               },
                                update: {
                                    url:   "operations/edit_phone_number.php?salesRepsId="+salesRepsId,
                                    type: "POST"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: "operations/delete_phone.php",
                                    type: "POST"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url:  "operations/add_phone.php?salesRepsId="+salesRepsId,
                                    type: "POST",
                                },
                            },
                            schema: {
                                data:"data",
                                total: "data.length", //total amount of records
                                model: {
                                    id: "PhoneId",
                                    fields: {
                                        PhoneType: { defaultValue: { PhoneTypeId: 1, PhoneTypeName: "Work"} },
                                        PhoneNumber: { type: "string" },
                                        IsMainPhone: {type: "boolean", editalbe:true},
                                     }
                                }

                            },
                            pageSize: 5,
                        },
                        height: 250,
                        filterable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        pageable: true,
                        reorderable: false,
                        groupable: false,
                        batch: true,
                        toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                        editable: true,
                        columns: [
                            {
                                field:"PhoneType",
                                title:"Type",
                                editor: PhoneTypeDropDownEditor,
                                template: "#=PhoneType.PhoneTypeName#" 
                            },
                            {
                                field: "PhoneNumber",
                                title:"Phone Number",

                            },
                             {
                                field: "IsMainPhone",
                                title:"Is Main",
                                width: 65,
                                template: function (e){
                                    if(e.IsMainPhone== true){
                                        return '<img align="center" src ="images/check-icon.png" />';
                                    }else{
                                        return '';
                                    }
                                }
                               // hidden: true

                            },
                            { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width: 90 },

                           ],


                    });

                 }
```

The code in the server side is (add_phone.php)

```
<?php
require_once("../lib/Phone.php");

$phone = array();
foreach($_POST as $name => $value){
    $phone[$name] = $value;
}
Phone::AddPhoneNumber($_GET["salesRepsId"], $phone);
?>
```

For the first time, I added a new record. add_phone.php is calling once and everything is working fine. For the second time (with out refresh the page) when I try to add a new record, add_phone.php is called twice. One of them contains the first record which has been added to database before and the second is the new the data.

in the result I have 3 records ( 2 same data of first insert) and one new.

This an example to make it clear ( inspect the post request with firebug)

first click on save button (false, (111) 111-1111, 4,Fax)  // after I enter this phone (111) 111-1111

second click on save button (false, (111) 111-1111, 4,Fax) in addition to (false, (222) 222-2222, 3,Work) // after I added this (222) 222-2222

Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

May be your ajax request raise an error. You can see it by subscribing to the error event of your datasource.

In case of error, the data are not synchronized in your datasource. In your case, I think your dataitem stay in "dirty mode" so the datasource try to insert them for each synchronization...